# PHP server and android as a client

Tags: php, android, sockets

I hava a subdomain under my university domain for example www.university.edu/~myname...My main goal is to send gps data from android device to a server running on this domain which is running google maps api and can pin point the location of the device.I want to run a server which can accept connections on this url, I tried searching and ended up with making a PHP server socket which can accept connections.

I have two questions:
1.How can I bind this socket to an IP because as far as I know subdomains don't have an IP 
2.What should I use to send data from my android device.

Thanks in advance

Comment: why not just get your own server?

Comment: Hi, Its a college project.I was hoping to utilise my own domain for this purpose.

Comment: Tell me one thing - will your php server be running on your college's server itself , or are you thinking of redirecting the request it to your personal server ?

Comment: @Tapan There is no mention of a personal server?

Comment: That is my question, can run a PHP server script on my domain or is it necessary to have a full domain to run a server and by server I simply mean PHP script which will be accepting connections on a socket..

Comment: I think you should be fine as you are not using a port number that has already been used for eg 80 , ps : just understood your question so deleting my answer